# How to uninstall ispconfig?

Tags: php

I have server from my hoster with preinstalled  ispconfig.
I want to remove this service, what should i do ?

any apt-get or other command ?

Answer (score 1):

**Follow these steps:**

1. Log in as root/
2. Go to your directory where ISP config is installed using the `cd` command.
3. Run the uninstall script:

   ```
   php -q uninstall.php
   ```

Done. ISPConfig will be uninstalled completely.